# How to pronounce Arthurian character "Menw" in English?

Tags: pronunciation

In some Arthurian tales a character named *"Menw"* occurs, e.g. from [Kilhwch and Olwen, or The Twrch Trwyth](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mabinogion/Kilhwch_and_Olwen): (emphasis added)

> And Arthur called **Menw** the son of Teirgwaedd, in order that if they went into a savage country, he might cast a charm and an illusion over them, so that none might see them whilst they could see every one.

I wonder how this name (of Welsh origin?) is pronounced in English; or if there is a conventional English pronunciation.

I browsed several dictionaries (Cambridge, Oxford, Webster), but I couldn't find an entry for "Menw", nor any similar names or words. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menw) but unfortunately it doesn't include the name's pronunciation.

If I were to guess, I'd pronounce it "Menew" or "Menoo", i.e. /menuː/ – the first part like **men** /men/ and the last part like **flew** /fluː/ or **boo** /buː/.

Can someone enlighten me, please? Am I on the right track?

Comment: It's not about the English language.

Comment: @dwjohnston what do you mean?

Comment: Better asked at Linguistics.  (like 'menu' without the /y/?) (cognate with 'minnow'?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Welsh not English.

Comment: @AndyT sure, the name is of Welsh origin. But the tales I'm referring to have been translated into English, so there's an English pronunciation for that name. That's what I was asking for.

Comment: That makes sense, but note that the source that user070221 quotes doesn't seem to be giving English pronunciations (at least, not fully nativized English pronunciations). It uses symbols and sounds like " ï = high-mixed open i" and "ɣ = voiced form of the voiceless x": most English speakers don't use these sounds at all.

Comment: @Stefan The fact that a story has been translated into English doesn’t mean that personal names in that story have conventional English pronunciations. In some cases, they do end up with English variants or pronunciations (_Hansel and Gretel_, for instance, or names from Greek mythology), but that doesn’t mean that translating a text makes its characters a matter of English language automatically. There are many names from the Welsh Mabinogion (Bendigeidfran, Branwen ferch Llŷr, Matholwch, etc.), for example, whose ‘English’ pronunciations are just approximations of the Welsh.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet so asking how "Hansel and Gretel" is pronounced in English would be regarded off-topic – really? If I were to read the English translation of "Kilhwch and Olwen" aloud, how could I know how to pronounce "Menw" correctly / appropriately? Asking at the _English Language & Usage Stack Exchange_ seemed like the obvious choice to me.

Comment: @Stefan Note that I didn’t say that it’s off-topic (though I think the question should be whether the name _has_ a conventional English pronunciation, and if so, what it is) – just that an English translation does not equal an English pronunciation of a name. Asking whether something does have a conventional reading in English is definitely on-topic, even if the answer turns out to be no (e.g., Väinämöinen does not, even though the _Kalevala_ has been translated into English – and we all remember how unconventionally _Eyjafjallajökull_ was pronounced a few years back!).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks for your welcoming feedback! I'm quite baffled that my question (my very first one here, actually) was closed and downvoted without any constructive commentary (at that time). Maybe there's a chance to have it re-opened – I don't think it's too bad as it is currently written. We'll see ...

Comment: So the answer provided by user070221 doesn't satisfy you? Do you think they may be other ways of pronouncing Menw? Please realize that it's an extraordinarily rare name in the UK. Knowing the answer to this question benefits... who? Just you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA of course the answer satisfies me, that's why I have accepted it.(maybe you missed the green check mark?) I was complaining about the closing and downvoting. Regarding other ways of pronunciation – I really don't know how to pronounce it, hence my question. And how do you come to the conclusion that it benefits just me? I'm pretty sure that I'm not the only one who stumbled over that name in the aforementioned tale(s). If the name was common, I didn't have to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menw](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/celt/cml/cml32.htm) (mɛnu).

> ɛ = open e
>
> (www.sacred-texts.com/neu/celt)

[Menw:](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/menw)

> The name Menw is a Welsh baby name. In Welsh the meaning of the name Menw is: Legendary son of Teinkaedd.
>
> — sheknows.com

Comment: Didn't know about www.sacred-texts.com – what a treasure!